# Appending a ? param to my website makes a element not render on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, url-parameters

This is a hard one for me to post code, but my project is open source so the code is here https://github.com/wispyco/conundrum-quest

What I have noticed is if I get a link from a referrer site with /? appended it breaks my site, the hero image section does not render/load

Here is an example

Working

https://www.conundrum.quest

Not working

https://www.conundrum.quest/?

Hopefully somebody could help me with this.

It's a next js app so the home page is in pages/index.js directory

Comment: Please do try to do some debugging on your own and update your question to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the code you think you've an issue with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you specifically mentioned that the route has to be root for this section to render. Just make this flexible with query perams enabled. Hope this helped.

[image]